# Django send_mail giving NoneType Error with RequestFactory, But Not When Running Code Outside of Views (Test Code Included)

Tags: python, django

So I am having issues with my website in production and figured it was something with Nginx while in production. But I have boiled it down to another issue, that I am not quite sure how to define.

The issue at hand is when using the `send_mail` function in Django (1.10.x). I can send emails perfectly when I run my function code from the terminal, just by typing it out while in a python shell. But when I try to run it using RequestFactory and running the given function with the request, I get an odd error.

This error on my terminal screen is much more clear than the blank 500 server error I receive on my website.

I have tried different email setups, even changing the email backend to console in the settings, and nothing is working.

**Code that works**, after opening up my shell `./manage.py shell_plus`

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> name = 'Test User'
>>> contact_email = 'testing@test.com'
>>> contact_phone = '123-456-7890'
>>> subject = 'Message from: %s, %s' % (name, contact_phone)
>>> message = 'This is a test being sent from the backend console.'
>>> to = 'user@test.com'  # changed for anonymity

>>> send_mail(subject, message, contact_email, [to], fail_silently=False)
>>> 1  # this is what's returned
```

**Code that doesn't work**

```
>>> from django.test import RequestFactory
>>> factory = RequestFactory()

>>> from views import contact  # the view that runs my send_mail function

>>> request = factory.get(contact)

>>> request.method = 'POST'  # needs to be POST method to trigger my view function that triggers the email function

>>> contact(request)  # this is where things go south
```

Let me clarify something before I post my errors. When `contact(request)` is run, it triggers a function called `contact_form` that contains the exact same code that is working in the above **code that works** segment.

Here is the long winded error that I get back, and because of it, I am at a loss.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/test/website/views.py", line 46, in contact
    request = utils.contact_form(request)
  File "/root/test/website/utils.py", line 20, in contact_form
    contact_phone = '123-456-7890'
  File "/root/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/root/test_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 348, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/root/test_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 111, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/root/test_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 125, in _send
    message = email_message.message()
  File "/root/test_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 307, in message
    msg = SafeMIMEText(self.body, self.content_subtype, encoding)
  File "/root/test_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 214, in __init__
    MIMEText.__init__(self, _text, _subtype=_subtype, _charset=_charset)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/text.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.set_payload(_text, _charset)
  File "/root/test_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 224, in set_payload
    for l in payload.splitlines()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

**Minor Tests After Error**

So I noticed this line: `File "/root/test/website/utils.py", line 20, in contact_form
        contact_phone = '123-456-7890'` and decided to comment it out in the function. I received the exact same error, just with a `#` before the `contact_phone` line.

I even deleted the `contact_phone` line entirely, and it just displayed the next line in code in that same error.

**EDIT**

Here is the breakdown of `request` in case it is of any help

```
>>> request.environ
{u'HTTP_COOKIE': u'', u'wsgi.multithread': False, 
u'SCRIPT_NAME': u'', 
u'wsgi.input': <django.test.client.FakePayload object at 0x7f12e169d850>, 
u'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 
u'PATH_INFO': u'<function contact at 0x7f12e226a050>',
u'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1', 
u'QUERY_STRING': '', 
u'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 
u'SERVER_NAME': 'testserver',
u'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
u'wsgi.run_once': False, u'wsgi.errors': <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f12e16329b0>,
u'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
u'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
u'SERVER_PORT': '80', u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'IicQMalE3nSO682lHcZQG3kI51X5f1P1wQwfFzLdv3EFjM2KdnUrlayjjsbrsOct',
u'CSRF_COOKIE_USED': True}
```

**MORE TESTING**

So I have moved the function that I am using to send mail, and placed it directly inside of the view function. But I did not even place it as a function itself, but rather just some variable assigning (with test values) and the send_mail function itself. Still getting a 500 error, and this is without even attempting to parse information from an HTML form.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `RequestFactory` wrong. It accepts a URL path (e.g., `/`), and not a view function which is what you are passing to it. You need to use the factory to generate a request object, and then pass *that* to your view function. Something like this:

```
from django.test import RequestFactory

request = RequestFactory().post('/')   # Use post() instead of get() if you're testing a post request
# Pass this request object to your view function
response = contact(request)
```

The [example in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/advanced/#example) for how to use `RequestFactory` is worth looking at in this context.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, it has been very helpful. With this information, I have gotten everything working beautifully. It seems my issue lies in the possibility of nginx not having the right permissions to actually send mail using postfix. Do you know what permissions I must set?

Comment: I don't thing nginx would have anything to do with postfix - it is Django itself that makes the connection to your mail server. As for why that is failing - can't really tell without knowing what error you get and how you have configured postfix.

Comment: it turns out it was a permissions issue. I don't have a permanent fix, but a temporary one for now. I am now running my gunicorn instance from /usr/bin/gunicorn, rather than my virtualenv gunicorn. I am not exactly sure why this works, but I am trying to figure out which permissions I need to adjust in order to use the virtualenv gunicorn with no problem...